# Give an example of a maximal ideal in a noncommutative ring which is not prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

While trying to find an example, I came up with this:

Since if $J$ is an ideal of a the ring $M_n(R)$, where $R$ is a commutative ring, then $J=M_n(I)$ for some ideal $I$ of $R$. IF I could show that for every maximal ideal $J$ of $R$, $M_n(J)$ is a maximal ideal of $M_n(R)$, then I could take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $J=2\mathbb{Z}$, then $M_n(2\mathbb{Z})$ will be a maximal ideal and I could cook up an example using $M_2(2\mathbb{Z})$ and the matrix $$ 
   M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

Clearly $M^2\in M_n(2\mathbb{Z})$ but $M \not \in M_n(2\mathbb{Z})$

Here is how I tried to prove: **for every maximal ideal $I$ of $R$, $M_n(I)$ is a maximal ideal of $M_n(R)$.**

Suppose $$M_n(I) \subseteq M_n(K) \subseteq M_n(R).$$ If $M_n(I) \ne M_n(K)$, then there exists an element $k_1 \in M_n(K)$ such that $k_1 \not \in M_n(I) $. let $$ 
   K_1=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a_{11} & a_{12} & . &. &a_{1n} \\
   a_{21} & a_{22} & . &. &a_{2n} \\
   .      & .      & . & .& .        \\
   a_{n1} & a_{n2} & . &. &a_{nn} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

Then there exists at least one $a_{ij} \in K$ such that $a_{ij} \not \in I$. But since $M_{n}(I) \subset M_n(K)$, $I \subset K$. BUt $I$ is maximal. Hence $K=R$. Thus $M_n(K)=M_n(R)$. So $M_n(I)$ is maximal.

IS is alright of a proof??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Are these left ideals, right ideals, two-sided ideals...? For two-sided ideals, what about $(0) \subset M_2(\mathbb{R})$ for example?

Comment: Maximal ideal needs to be a proper subset. Two sided ideals @NajibIdrissi

Comment: Nothing says $(0)$ cannot be a maximal ideal; it's $R$ that cannot be a maximal ideal. In fact, in a field $(0)$ is a maximal ideal. $(0)$ also a maximal two-sided ideal in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ which isn't prime.

Comment: @rschwieb I came upon this from the title itself.. so the title

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your reasoning is valid that if $M_n(I)\subsetneq M_n(K) \subseteq M_n(R)$, then $I\subsetneq K\subseteq R$, and so if $I$ is maximal, $M_n(I)$ is maximal.

---

As for the title question, a maximal ideal in a noncommutative ring *is* always prime, unless you mean to apply the commutative definition of prime ideals to noncommutative rings. The general definition of "prime ideal" is "$AB\subseteq P\implies A\subseteq P \text{ or } B\subseteq P$."

In noncommutative algebra, an ideal that satisfies $ab\in I\implies a\in I \text{ or } b\in I$ is  called a *completely prime* ideal, and the zero ideal of a matrix ring over a field is an example of a maximal ideal that isn't completely prime.

The example you gave is a maximal and prime ideal of $M_n(\Bbb Z)$ which is not a *completely prime* ideal.

Comment: SO you are suggesting my example is wrong?

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam No, I am not saying that. It would be correct to say you gave a valid example of a prime, but **not completely prime** ideal of $M_n(\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam It seems to me you're probably asking a natural question, but not using "prime" in a standard way. I'm letting you know what the standard usage is, and confirming (what I believe is) your idea.