# Let R be a ring and M a maximal ideal on R, let x,y∈R such that xy∈M, prove that x∈M or y∈M

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I Need help to prove this:

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ a maximal ideal of $R$, let $x,y\in R$ such that $xy\in M$, prove that $x\in M$ or $y\in M.$

R is commutative ring with identity 
I tried to prove M is a prime ideal but i couldn't figured  it out

Comment: Welcome to MSE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a reference for MathJax. Please keep in mind that this is *not* a "do my homework for me" site. You will find more help here if you add your thought and/or work. This question, as it stands now, will attract negative votes and will be closed. (Also, don't be discouraged by negative votes; it will help you to understand [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)).

Comment: $R$ is a ring with identity? Commutative or non-commutative? What you have tried? Please add these in the "body" of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*By contrapositive*:

Suppose neither $x$ nor $y$ belong to $M$. Then $(x,M)$ and $(y,M)$ strictly contain $M$.  $M$ being maximal, these ideals  are equal to $R$, which means there exist $a, b\in R$ and $m,n\in M$ such that $ax+m=1$, $by+n=1$. Multiply them:
$$1=(ax+m)(by+n)=abxy+axn+bym+mn.$$
In the last sum, the last three terms belong to $M$, so the the first cannot be in $M$ since $1$ doesn't. This implies that $xy$ doesn't belong to $M$.

*Added* – A shorter-better proof by @egreg:

We prove that if one of $x, y$ doesn't lie in $M$, the other does. Say $y\notin M$. As $M$ is maximal, this means there exists $b\in R,\: n\in M$, such that $by+n=1$, so
$$x=x(by+n)=b(xy)+xn\in M.$$

Comment: I think the direct way is simpler: if $y\notin M$, then $1=yr+z$ for $r\in R$ and $z\in M$; then $x=xyr+xr\in M$.

Comment: @egreg: Much shorter than  the contrapositive indeed. If you don't mind, I'll add it to my answer (with due credits,of course).

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

> $xy\in M \implies $ $x\in M$ or $y\in M$

*Hint:* This condition defines prime ideals. Prove that every maximal ideal is prime by considering $R/M$.

(I assume that $R$ is a commutative ring with unit.)

Comment: Yes, in the assumption that the ring is commutative.

Comment: @Math_QED, yes, of course. Otherwise: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973066/give-an-example-of-a-maximal-ideal-in-a-noncommutative-ring-which-is-not-prime